# Could you tell me where I can find specification of simple_item_list_1 or simple_item_list_2?

Tags: android

Could you tell me where I can find specification of simple_item_list_1 or simple_item_list_2?
Or tell me how to use them both?

Comment: What is simple_item_list_1? I know only simple_list_item_1.xml and what do you mean under specification?

Answer (score 0):

You can find these resources, and others, in your SDK. They are in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/$VERSION/data/res`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is where you unpacked the SDK on your machine, and `$VERSION` is some Android version (e.g., `android-8` for Android 2.2).

Comment: Okay. I can read source of this XML files, but I still don't know, what object I have to give to contructor of ArrayAdapter, when I use simple_list_item_2. For example, for simple_list_item_1, constructor of ArrayAdapter looks like this: new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"Car", "Cat"});

Comment: @kspacja: `ArrayAdapter` doesn't support `simple_list_item_2`. Here is a sample project showing the user of `simple_list_item_1`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/

Comment: How to do this with simple_list_item_1 I know. How do I know, that ArrayAdapter doesn't support simple_list_item_2? How do I know what support what?